# Error rango fechas php DateTime

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

Obtengo el siguiente error, estoy tratando de hacer un filtro de rango por fechas, estoy usando `CodeIgniter 3x`, mando las siguientes fechas por `AJAX` a `PHP`:

```
$fecha1 = 21/07/2017;
$fecha2 = 21/07/2017;
```

De esta forma separo las fecha del campo ejemplo : `21/07/2017 - 22/07/2017`, por lo que leí es por que al hacer el `split` queda como un `string`, de que forma tendría que convertirlo a `date`?

`JS`:

```
  var str = value.split("-");
  var rango1= $.trim(str[0]);
  var rango2= $.trim(str[1]);

      var ParamObjSend={
             'fecha_rango1' : rango1,   
             'fecha_rango2' : rango2,               
      }
```

Verifique que los datos llegan correctamente a `PHP`.

El error me lo marca en la linea :

```
$fecha_reserva1 = new DateTime($fecha1);
```

> Message: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string
>   (21/07/2017 ) at position 0 (2): Unexpected character

```
public function RangoFecha(){

    $fecha1                                  =$this->input->post('fecha_rango1');
    $fecha2                                  =$this->input->post('fecha_rango2');
    $fecha_reserva1                          =new DateTime($fecha1);
    $fecha_reserva2                          =new DateTime($fecha2);
    $Where['agenda.fecha_reserva>=']  =date_format($fecha_reserva1,'Y-m-d');
    $Where['agenda.fecha_reserva<=']  =date_format($fecha_reserva2,'Y-m-d');

    $Where['agenda.tipo']='Cita';
    $resultado = $this->Model->ListarAgenda($Where);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error aparece porque `DateTime`, no entiende el formato en el que se encuentra la fecha.

### Solución:

Podrías usar [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.createfromformat.php) para parsear la fecha.

Ejemplo:

```
public function RangoFecha(){

    $fecha1                           =$this->input->post('fecha_rango1');
    $fecha2                           =$this->input->post('fecha_rango2');
    $fecha_reserva1                   =DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $fecha1);
    $fecha_reserva2                   =DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $fecha2);
    $Where['agenda.fecha_reserva>=']  =$fecha_reserva1->format('Y-m-d');
    $Where['agenda.fecha_reserva<=']  =$fecha_reserva2->format('Y-m-d');

    $Where['agenda.tipo']='Cita';
   $resultado = $this->Model->ListarAgenda($Where);
}
```

--

Con respecto al `split` que usas para obtener las fechas, si el `string` es exactamente este `21/07/2017 - 22/07/2017`, entonces lo correcto seria hacer hacer de `" - "` (*con un espacio antes y después del guion-medio*).

Demo:

```js
var fechas = '21/07/2017 - 22/07/2017';
console.log('Split por "-"', fechas.split('-'), " deja espacios en las fechas");
console.log('Split por " - "', fechas.split(' - '), "no dejas espacios");
```

Comment: gracias estimado lo solucione !